# Integrating Bitcoin payment methods to a UK Opencart store?

Tags: payment, ecommerce, payment-processors

I really want to integrate Bitcoin into my girlfriend's web store, but have found that they are either too expensive per transaction for international payments (bips.me - $7.50), have a huge minimum withdrawal threshold for international bank accounts (bitpay - $1,000) or simply don't work with international bank accounts at all (coinbase)

Is there any payment module I've overlooked that will work with Opencart, and will pay in £GBP to a UK bank account?

Thanks

Comment: Large withdraw fees apply for USD, not for bitcoins. You can receive Bitcoins to a wallet and then exchange em to fiat with whatever your favorite exchange is. Bitpay can forward to an address on file and has a .01 BTC settlement threshold for it.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that, thank you... that could be a really good solution, my only concern is that she wants it to be as hassle free as possible and (unfortunately, imo) has zero interest in having any Bitcoins, she just wants it as a payment method, and then not having the potential headache of converting them afterwards (plus potential for Capital Gains Tax etc?)

Answer (score 1):

> but have found that they are either too expensive per transaction for international payments (bips.me - $7.50), have a huge minimum withdrawal threshold for international bank accounts (bitpay - $1,000) or simply don't work with international bank accounts at all (coinbase)

First of all if you think that $7.50 is too expensive for international wires or $1000 is too large a minimum payout amount then I can only assume you've never received an international wire before. The SWIFT system that is used for international bank to bank wire transfers is very expensive and it can easily cost you $60-70 in fees per wire.

With SWIFT the sender doesn't even know about all those fees. Intermediate banks can deduct arbitrary fees without first informing either the sender or the recipient. You won't know how much the wire really cost you until you receive the amount. What I can tell you is that $1000 is the smallest amount you can practically send via SWIFT.

Second bips.me is not a reliable company. They got hacked in 2013 and lost a lot of their customer's money. Bitpay and Coinbase are the most reputable providers in this space. You may also want to look into coinpayments.net

Thirdly I suggest looking at UK or Euro Area companies because those might be willing to send you payments via SEPA. This is a bank wire transfer system used in the EU. AFAIK it is cheaper than SWIFT.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered https://spectrocoin.com/en/merchant/integration/plugins.html there is also live technical support if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Did you look at https://cryptopay.me/merchant/tools ?

There are several ways to add payment to your site, adding a bitcoin button, hosted pages or iframe. Adding GBP funds and withdrawing BTC is free, I tried these, and the exchange rate is not the worst either.